# Not able to install any apps with command apt-get install

Tags: linux, apt-get, debian-jessie

I have recently installed Debian 8 (Jessie) and when I try to install an app, the message:

> A media change is required. Please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.7.1_Jessie_-Official amd64 DVD Binary - 1 20170116-11:01' to continue

appears to me and I can't install anything.

I have made the change in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it is still not repaired:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you insert the disc? Or maybe you want to pull software off the internet? Please elaborate.

Comment: Nothing happens when I insert a CD

Comment: What is listed in your software sources?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your system tries to install software from a CD-ROM / DVD instead of the Internet.

You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (use `sudo`; the file is only writable by super users) and comment out the `cdrom` entry by prefixing it with a `#`.

Make sure your file contains the respective entries needed for your distribution, which you can check here: https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

Save the file, then run `apt-get update` and you should be good.

Comment: I have made the change on /etc/apt/sources.list but now  apt-get install doesn't found me any app.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after editing the file? What happens when you mean "doesn't find any app"? Any specific error?